# how to pass login data from one controller to another other than using rootscope, in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i am new to AngularJS and trying to create a sample login application.
i am facing issue in passing/sharing the input text field values among two or more controllers.
Want to pass the login username after successful login to homepage. Using $rootscope works, but clicking the refresh button makes it null.
please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update $scope value from another controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41974077/update-scope-value-from-another-controller)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), which will help you a lot with multiple pages. Not just that but help with passing information from one state to another (one page to another). [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41307705/angularjs-pass-data-from-one-view-to-another-with-in-same-controller/41308344#41308344) is an answer to a similar question that will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values around your app from controller to controller by simply having a code like

in a js file

```
var myApp = {};
myApp.storeUserItem= function(key, value) {
    if (window.localStorage) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value); //stores value 
    } else {
        ....your error message
    }
};
```

to retrieve later just have a

```
myApp.retrieveUserItem= function(key) {
        if (window.localStorage) {
            localStorage.getItem(key); //stores value 
        } else {
            ....your error message
        }
    };
```

later in a controller you have the initial

```
myApp.storeUserItem("username", $scope.userNameValue);
```

and the retrieve

```
$scope.username = myApp.retrieveUserItem("username");
```

simple call used quite often across all angular apps